# como hacer que la información de buscar aparezca en una tabla y no en varias?

Tags: php, mysql

cree una tabla en php que me entregará todos los registros de km de una patente que esta almacenados en una BD mysql, la idea es que me entregue todos los registros de una patente en particular pero me entrega varias tablas y solo quiero que aparezca una con los registros, o con los últimos 10 registros, pero solo en una tabla.

Esto es lo que intente.

```
<form method="post">
      <center>
        <h4>Recorrido Km</h4>
   <label for="" >Ingrese Patente en Mayúscula y sin guion:
   </label>
 </center>
 <center>
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="Patente" placeholder="Patente">
   <input type="submit" value="buscar" name="buscar">
 </center>
</form>

<?php
   if(isset($_POST['buscar']))
   {
  include("conexion.php");
      $Patente = $_POST['Patente'];
  $consu="SELECT Patente, Fecha_Reg, Km
FROM Km
WHERE Patente='$Patente'";
  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consu);
   while($consu = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{

echo "<br>";
  echo
  "
  <table width=\"60%\" border=\"1\">
    <tr>
   <td><b><center>Patente</center></b></td>
   <td><b><center>Fecha_Reg</center></b></td>
   <td><b><center>Km</center></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>".$consu['Patente']."</td>
    <td>".$consu['Fecha_Reg']."</td>
    <td>".$consu['Km']."</td>
    </tr>
</table>
";

}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que sacar la cabecera y el final de la tabla del bucle, y dejar dentro solo las filas que se van generando dinámicamente.

Es decir, esto:

```php
while($consu = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{

echo "<br>";
  echo
  "
  <table width=\"60%\" border=\"1\">
    <tr>
   <td><b><center>Patente</center></b></td>
   <td><b><center>Fecha_Reg</center></b></td>
   <td><b><center>Km</center></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>".$consu['Patente']."</td>
    <td>".$consu['Fecha_Reg']."</td>
    <td>".$consu['Km']."</td>
    </tr>
</table>
";

}
```

lo cambias por esto:

```php
echo "
<br>
<table width=\"60%\" border=\"1\">
  <tr>
    <td><b><center>Patente</center></b></td>
    <td><b><center>Fecha_Reg</center></b></td>
    <td><b><center>Km</center></b></td>
  </tr>
";
while($consu = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{
  echo
  "
  <tr>
    <td>".$consu['Patente']."</td>
    <td>".$consu['Fecha_Reg']."</td>
    <td>".$consu['Km']."</td>
  </tr>
";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Prueba y nos cuentas.

Comment: muchas gracias, si me ha funcionado.